# How to Create a ListView with Text and Images in Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I Found this good Tutorial on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRANgDgM2Zg which is exactly what i want to do. 
Cant find anything for Xamarin so i decided to try it in Xamarin

I Created my User Profile Like this;

using System;

```
namespace ListViewTest
{
    public class UserProfile
    {
        private string name;
        private int ProfileID;
        private int ImageID;

        public UserProfile (string name, int ProfileID, int ImageID)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.ProfileID = ProfileID;
            this.ImageID = ImageID;
        }

        public string GetName(){
            return name;
        }

        public int GetProfileID(){
            return ProfileID;
        }

        public int GetImageID(){
            return ImageID;
        }

    }
}
```

But when trying to create a instance of it like this:

```
List<UserProfile> myProfiles = new ArrayList<UserProfile>();
```

it says " The Type or namespace name 'ArrayList could not be found are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" this message comes up on ArrayList

I'm Not sure what is missing?

Comment: Have you added `using path.to.UserProfile` in the class you are creating instance of `UserProfile`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like **ArrayList<>** in C#. Means there is no generic implementation for ArrayList. Because in ArrayList you can store any type of object, so there is no meaning of providing it generic.

in that case you can use

```
List<UserProfile> myProfiles = new List<UserProfile>();
```

Also suggest you that you can change your Get methods to properties like :

```
private string name;
public string Name
{
    get { return name; }
}
```